# Replace new lines with spaces using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I have a text file that I generated of all files in a directory. I'd like to use this file as input into a script that I have, but I need the text file to be formatted in a particular way to be parsed correctly.

Currently the text file, which is a list of file names, is formatted like so:

```
A1_R1.fastq.gz
A1_R2.fastq.gz
A2_R1.fastq.gz
A2_R2.fastq.gz
A3_R1.fastq.gz
A3_R2.fastq.gz
```

I need the paired reads (files with the same name, but different `RN` values) for each sample to be on the same line, separated by a tab:

```
A1_R1.fastq.gz A1_R2.fastq.gz
A2_R1.fastq.gz A2_R2.fastq.gz
A3_R1.fastq.gz A3_R2.fastq.gz
```

Since I have >1000 entries, I am hoping for a method using awk or something similar to modify the file, but I don't have much experience with awk.

Comment: Hello, do you mean you have a `R1` and `R2` file for every prefix (`A1`, `A2`, etc.)? Thx.

Comment: Do you need to explicitly match the prefixes, or can you simply take pairs of lines and place them side by side? If the latter, something like `paste - - <yourfile` would suffice.

Comment: Yes, @jubilatious1 sorry just edited the OG post, I have a R1 and R2 file for every prefix

I need to match prefixes and put the two reads side by side

Comment: Does it matter whether `A1_R1` comes before or after `A1_R2` on the output line for that pair?

Comment: Does each of your pairs of associated `_R1` and `_R2` files come together in the listing, one immediately following the other?

Answer (score 12):

Assuming that the lines are ordered in the manner that you show in the question, then the `paste` command can do that:

```
$ paste - - < input_file
A1_R1.fastq.gz  A1_R2.fastq.gz
A2_R1.fastq.gz  A2_R2.fastq.gz
A3_R1.fastq.gz  A3_R2.fastq.gz
```

If you want the columns to be separated by anything other than the default TAB then use the `-d` option of `paste`. For a simple space:

```
$ paste -d ' ' - -  <input_file
```

Comment: See also `paste -sd '\t\n' input_file` which avoids a trailing tab if the input has an odd number of lines (though note it produces one empty line on empty input).

Answer (score 9):

For the input you show where all the paired lines are next to each other all you need with any awk is:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%2 ? "\t" : RS)} 1' file
A1_R1.fastq.gz  A1_R2.fastq.gz
A2_R1.fastq.gz  A2_R2.fastq.gz
A3_R1.fastq.gz  A3_R2.fastq.gz
```

or if they aren't paired already:

```
$ shuf file > file1
$ cat file1
A3_R2.fastq.gz
A2_R2.fastq.gz
A1_R1.fastq.gz
A3_R1.fastq.gz
A1_R2.fastq.gz
A2_R1.fastq.gz
```

and so need to be paired then if you don't mind adding a call to `sort`:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%2 ? "\t" : RS)} 1' <(sort file1)
A1_R1.fastq.gz  A1_R2.fastq.gz
A2_R1.fastq.gz  A2_R2.fastq.gz
A3_R1.fastq.gz  A3_R2.fastq.gz
```

or to pair them within awk:

```
$ awk -F'_' -v OFS='\t' '$1 in a{print a[$1], $0; next} {a[$1]=$0}' file1
A3_R2.fastq.gz  A3_R1.fastq.gz
A1_R1.fastq.gz  A1_R2.fastq.gz
A2_R2.fastq.gz  A2_R1.fastq.gz
```

Note in that last script that the R2 field is output before it's R1 partner in some cases. If that's an issue then you can order them when printing:

```
$ awk -F'_' -v OFS='\t' '
    $1 in a { print (a[$1] < $0 ? a[$1] OFS $0 : $0 OFS a[$1]); next }
    { a[$1] = $0 }
' file1
A3_R1.fastq.gz  A3_R2.fastq.gz
A1_R1.fastq.gz  A1_R2.fastq.gz
A2_R1.fastq.gz  A2_R2.fastq.gz
```

If your input file is actually many millions of lines long then adding `delete a[$1];` before the `next` would speed up execution time in most cases, probably not worthwhile if it's just a few thousand (trading off the overhead of calling `delete a[$1]` for every pair vs the overhead of having a large hash table `a[]`).

If you need the output lines also sorted then you'd need to use GNU awk for `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`:

```
$ awk '{a[$0]} END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"; for (i in a) printf "%s%s", i, (++n % 2 ? "\t" : RS) }' file1
A1_R1.fastq.gz  A1_R2.fastq.gz
A2_R1.fastq.gz  A2_R2.fastq.gz
A3_R1.fastq.gz  A3_R2.fastq.gz
```

but, just like the solution that uses `sort`, that wouldn't produce the presumably expected order when the numbers in the input can be multiple digits because, for example, `A11` would sort alphabetically before `A2` - you'd need to split each string up into separate alphabetic and numeric parts and sort each separately or normalize them to always have the same number oc alphabetic and numeric characters in each position, e.g. map `A1_R1` into `000A0001_000R0001` or similar before sorting.

Answer (score 4):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

---

*If it's always paired reads, and they're always in the correct order:*

```
~$ raku -e '.put for lines.rotor(2);'  file
```

*If it's always paired reads, but filenames are out-of-order:*

```
~$ raku -e '.put for lines.sort.rotor(2);'  file
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl family. Similar to the excellent `awk` answer by @EdMorton, if you have to sort the filenames the resultant order will be alphabetic.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/lines
https://docs.raku.org/routine/rotor
https://raku.org

---

*If sometimes files are missing, regardless of filename order:*

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my %hash;     \  
             %hash.append: .match(/^ (<-[_]>+) _ /).[0]  =>  $_;   \
             END for %hash.sort { .values.put };'   file

#OR

~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my %hash;     \ 
             %hash.append: m/^ (<-[_]>+) _ /.[0]  =>  $_;    \
             END for %hash.sort { .values.put };'   file
```

This second approach is if the input data is less-than-pristine (missing filenames, etc.). Like Perl itself, Raku has an `awk`-like command-line mode invoked with the `-ne` ("non-autoprinting linewise") flags. Above, we `BEGIN` by declaring a `%hash`. In the body of this "one-liner" each line is `.match`ed on (here `.match` is short for `$_.match` meaning to call the function on `$_`, the topic variable which holds the line text).

The `.match` (or `m/ … /`) routine/operator looks for `^` beginning-of-line followed by `<-[_]>+` one-or-more of any-character-but `_` underscore (i.e. a custom negative character class), followed by `_` underscore itself. (FYI, a custom *positive* character class looks like so: `<+[ … ]>`). Parentheses capture the leading non-underscore text into `$0` or more simply `.[0]`.

Each line is thus deciphered into `.[0]` as `key` with `$_` (the whole line) as `value`. The  `=>`  is used to create a key/value pair. Hash data structures maintain unique `keys`, so every time the same `key` is encountered, the new value simply gets `append`ed. At the `END` of reading lines, we `sort` the keys, and out`put` the `.values` per key.

https://course.raku.org/essentials/associatives/hashes/
https://docs.raku.org/language/hashmap
https://raku.org

---

Sample Input:

```
A1_R1.fastq.gz
A1_R2.fastq.gz
A2_R1.fastq.gz
A2_R2.fastq.gz
A3_R1.fastq.gz
A3_R2.fastq.gz
```

Sample Output (either approach):

```
A1_R1.fastq.gz A1_R2.fastq.gz
A2_R1.fastq.gz A2_R2.fastq.gz
A3_R1.fastq.gz A3_R2.fastq.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably start out with the simplest approach:

```
$ fmt -w30 < files.csv | tr ' ' '\t'
A1_R1.fastq.gz  A1_R2.fastq.gz
A2_R1.fastq.gz  A2_R2.fastq.gz
A3_R1.fastq.gz  A3_R2.fastq.gz
```

But if your heart is set on using `awk`, that's straightforward:

```
$ sort  < files.csv |
  awk 'NR % 2 == 0 {print prev"\t"$0}   {prev = $0}'
A1_R1.fastq.gz  A1_R2.fastq.gz
A2_R1.fastq.gz  A2_R2.fastq.gz
A3_R1.fastq.gz  A3_R2.fastq.gz
```

We're looking at low bit of NumberofRecord to
trigger on every other line.
You could always substitute a pattern match if you feel that's clearer.

Comment: What does `fmt -w29` do?

Comment: OP's filenames had length 14. What you see is copy-n-paste output from a run of BSD / MacOS `fmt` -- OP did not specify an execution platform. I refer you to the fmt man page: "_Lines are joined or split only at white space_". When porting this solution to fmt (GNU coreutils) 8.32, I see they apparently introduced an OBOB or made an undocumented change in the meaning of "_maximum line width_", as we find that at least `fmt -w30` is needed. (I will update my Answer to use `30`.)

Comment: Not sure I understand. Let's say `A1`, `A2`, etc. are primer-set names, and `R1`/`R2` are the paired reads. The sequencing software outputs files with these two strings joined via `_` underscore. But what happens if some primer-set names are `A1`, `A2`,  etc., while others are `GTAAAACGACGGCCAG` (i.e. the string length varies from primer-set to primer-set)?

Comment: @jubilatious1, when you're posing the Question, you get to make up the specification. I was just going with what the OP said. If `fmt -w30` (or e.g. `-w40`) is the Simplest Thing that Could Possibly Work, then go with that and move on. Otherwise, conservatively choose the robust `awk` approach, at the expense of greater complexity. (I conservatively threw in a `sort`, as well, to hedge against possible ordering ambiguity.) As it stands, I don't know and you don't know whether a GTAAAACGACGGCCAG.csv.gz or A7\tR1\t.fastq.gz file will appear in OP's environment, and that is out-of-scope.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand your `fmt` approach, because it seems powerful. However AIUI to use `fmt` an end-user has to make the assumption that input linewise character lengths ('filenames', in this example), are non-varying. The `fmt` approach could work just fine for some identifiers (e.g. Ensembl_IDs (such as `ENSRNOG00000000007`, `ENSRNOG00000071217`, etc.), which seemingly maintain consistent length. Thank you.

Comment: @jubilatious1 Depending on the naming scheme of the files, they definitely do not need to be of uniform length (it is common to use species names as a part of the filename, and the length of these varies greatly). I would advise against using this approach (with `fmt`) as a _generic_ solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of `sed`, and it can join adjacent pairs of lines pretty easily:

```
sed 'N; s/\n/'$'\t''/' < input > output
```

The `$'\t'` in the middle of that is a bash-ism conveying a single tab character, not directly related to `sed`.  In practice, I would probably use a literal tab character instead, but that does not come across clearly in this medium: `sed 'N; s/\n/   /' < input > output`

Explanation:

- `sed` starts by reading the first line
- the `N` instructs `sed` to read the next line of input and append it to the current one, separated by a newline.
- the `s` command replaces the newline with a tab.
- there being no more commands, the result of the previous steps is written, then `sed` reads the next line and cycles back
- `sed` terminates when it exhausts its input.